# Perform n linear regressions, simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have y - a 100 row by 5 column Pandas DataFrame

I have x - a 100 row by 5 column Pandas DataFrame

For i=0,...,4 I want to regress y[:,i] against x[:,i].

I know how to do it using a loop.

But is there a way to vectorise the linear regression, so that I don't have the loop in there?

Comment: you could run it in parallel using e.g. a pool of processes, but whether it would be worth the overhead of setting up the processes and communicating data back and forth is debatable

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no way to put this all at once in the optimized Fortran library, LAPACK, since each regression is it's own independent optimization problem.

note that the loop over 4 items is not taking any time relative to the regression itself, that you need to fully compute because each regression is an isolated linear algebra problem... so I don't think there is much time to save here...

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to get the data in ine single Dataframe it should be possible using 'apply'.
I cannot test it at the moment, but i think of something like this:
Create a single DF with MultiIndex:

```
i row x y 
0 0 1.1 2.2 
... 
0 99 3.14 2.3 
1 0 2.2 3.3 
... 
1 99 4.5 3.5 
2 0 ... ...
```

and then you can group by the 'i' column and apply an arbitrary function to the subgroup.

```
def linear_fit(sub_df):
    do_linear_fit(sub_df['x'], sub_df['y'])

df.groupby('i').apply(linear_fit)
```

I hope that helps, otherwise I can provide more help...

But keep in mind what @Retozi already mentioned. This will not be notably faster than a loop (it's not running in parallel or 'simultaneously'), but it is of course much nicer to read and the pythonic/pandas way of doing this...